# Partial download with wget

Tags: curl, command-line, wget

I see `curl` supports partial downloads:

```
-r, --range RANGE   Retrieve only the bytes within a range
```

Example:

```
curl -r 0-99 http://example.com/bar.mp4
```

However, can `wget` accomplish something similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately `wget` doesn't have this feature(at least with my `GNU Wget 1.10.2 (Red Hat modified)`), which is very annoying. You can send the Range header with HTTP request, but doesn't work.

```
wget "http://www.example.com"  -c --header="Range: bytes=0-99"
```

It returns

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Giving up.
```

It seemed that the wget had the proper response, but strangely, it didn't finish it. For example with verbose mode output:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.0 206 Partial Content
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Cache-Control: max-age=604800
  Content-Range: bytes 0-99/1270
  Content-Type: text/html
  Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 08:35:18 GMT
  Etag: "359670651"
  Expires: Fri, 31 Jan 2014 08:35:18 GMT
  Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
  Server: ECS (ftw/FBA9)
  X-Cache: HIT
  Content-Length: 100
  Connection: keep-alive
Giving up.
```

Comment: i see exact the same result. is it normal? does the parital content is downloaded successfully?

Comment: See the [wget issue #20416](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=20416)