# Download partial file from FTP using wget bash command

Tags: bash, wget

There are some huge files at my FTP server. I am making sure whether the file is properly formatted or not looking at only the top 10 records.
Currently I am downloading the whole file using the bash command `wget` to perform this operation.

Is there a way to specify size or number of lines to download using `wget`? I have checked the `-Q` option, but that works only if we provide a list of urls. If this can be achieved using any other command please help me with that.

Comment: Check this out-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323442/partial-download-with-wget

Comment: Maybe try `curl -r 0-999 <YourServer>`