# Is it possible to download a low resolution version of a high resolution image from any URL?

Tags: curl, wget, libcurl

So, I was just doing wget of an image. And while it was downloading, I aborted the process and I was able to see half of the image. So, I was thinking maybe we could get the server into thinking that I’ve already downloaded most part of image. 
Could you please provide some technical reading or if it is very simple, give a little more explanation as to why it is not possible?

Comment: Yes, with curl but not with wget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323442/partial-download-with-wget You might also find it interesting to read about progressive JPEG

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://superuser.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.